# Python - Beautifulsoup | ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "<div"

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I an trying to scrape an application off of the fareham.gov.uk web page and every time I try it returns an error instead of the reference number. Can somebody help me to fix this problem? I am new to web scraping and whenever I try to google a fix nothing worked.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DBaldwin\Desktop\sel.py", line 39, in <module>
    div = soup.select('<div Class="docGridRow"><div Class="detailsCells detailsFieldNames">Reference</div><div Class="detailsCells detailsValues">')
  File "C:\Users\DBaldwin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1477, in select
    'Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "%s"' % token)
ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "<div"
```

Code:

```
import time
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://www.fareham.gov.uk/casetrackerplanning/applicationsearch.aspx"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\DBaldwin\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_id("lnkAllowCookies").click()

def rerun():
    driver.find_element_by_id("BodyPlaceHolder_uxLinkButtonShowAdvancedSearch").click()

    time.sleep(3)

    driver.find_element_by_id("uxStartDateDecisionTextBox").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("uxStartDateDecisionTextBox").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("uxStartDateDecisionTextBox").send_keys("1/8/2018")

    driver.find_element_by_id("uxStopDateDecisionTextBox").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("uxStopDateDecisionTextBox").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("uxStopDateDecisionTextBox").send_keys("308/2018")

    driver.find_element_by_id("BodyPlaceHolder_uxButtonSearch").click()

    time.sleep(3)

rerun()

elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("searchResultsCell")

for e in elements:
    e.click()
    newUrl = driver.current_url
    go = urllib.request.urlopen(newUrl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(go.read(), "html.parser")
    div = soup.select('<div Class="docGridRow"><div Class="detailsCells detailsFieldNames">Reference</div><div Class="detailsCells detailsValues">')
    test = div[0].get_text()
    print(test)
    driver.back()
    rerun()
    print("Worked???")
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [bs4 documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)? `select` is used with css selectors synthax, not html.

Comment: then how can I fix it

Comment: I can't really understand what you are trying to do here. What do you want to select?

Comment: `div = soup.select('div.docGridRow)`?

Comment: Daniel Roseman
I am trying to scrape the reference number on one of the applications on that website, if you go to the link in the variable "url" it will ask for a date. Type in 1/8/2018 on start and 30/8/2018 on end, click the first application and you will see a reference id and other things, I am trying to make it scrape that

Comment: Andersson that worked! Could you make it an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Why do you need to make an HTTP-request to get page while it's already opened in browser? You can simply scrape it with Selenium built-ins

Comment: because I am new and dunno what to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use below code to get required values

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".searchResultsCell a")
links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in elements]

for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.docGridRow').text)
```